# Let $V$ be a vector space over $C$, prove that a set is a real vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> problem: if $V$ is a vector space over $\Bbb C$ withb dimension $n$. We say map $φ$  from $V$ to $V$ is conjugate if for any $\alpha,\beta ∈V$ and $λ∈\Bbb C$  ,$φ(\alpha +\beta)=φ(\alpha)+φ(\beta),φ(λ\alpha)=\bar λ φ(\alpha),φ^2(α)=α$. Let $R_φ(V)$=$\{α∈V|φ(α)=α \}$. Prove that $R_φ(V)$=$\{α∈V|φ(α)=α\}$ is a real vector space with dimension $n$.

**may attempt**:we can check $R_φ(V)$ is a vector space over $\Bbb R$. So the last is to prove $R_φ(V)$ has a basis with $n$ element.
Form the name of $φ$,we can find for any $α∈V$, $α=\frac{α+φ(α)}{2} +i\frac{α-φ(α)}{2i} $, we see $\frac{α+φ(α)}{2}$ and  $\frac{α-φ(α)}{2i} $ belongs to $R_φ(V)$ and this expression is unique. So i choose a basis $\{e_i|1≤i≤n \} $ of $V$. I want to prove that the real part $\{α_i=\frac{e_i+φ(e_i)}{2}|1≤i≤n \} $ is a basis of $R_φ(V)$,but it is may not a basis of $R_φ(V)$ because if we have equality $x_1α_1+\cdots+x_nα_n=0$, we have
$φ(x_1e_1+\cdots+x_ne_n)=-(x_1e_1+\cdots+x_ne_n)$,but we say $\{α∈V|φ(α)=-α \}$ contain nonzero element.